# Dynamic char buffer C

Tags: c, linux, malloc, buffer

Below is part of my code to read data from a text file, strip out the HTML and print out just the normal text. This all work swell but i am having a problem with reading all of the text file. How would i read the entire text file, understand that i will probably need to use malloc but am unsure of how to do so.

```
int i, nRead, fd;
int source;
char buf[1024];
int idx = 0;
int opened = 0;

if((fd = open("data.txt", O_RDONLY)) == -1)
{
    printf("Cannot open the file");
}
else
{
    nRead = read(fd, buf, 1024);
    printf("Original String ");
    for(i=0; i<nRead; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", buf[i]);
    }

    printf("\nReplaced String ");

    for(i=0; i<nRead; i++)
    {
        if(buf[i]=='<') {
            opened = 1;
        } else if (buf[i] == '>') {
            opened = 0;
        } else if (!opened) {
            buf[idx++] = buf[i];
        }           
        //printf("%c", buf[i]);
    }
}
    buf[idx] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buf);
close(source);
```

Comment: You have to loop over `read` calls until you get `0`, keep track of the amount you've read, and append it to the buffer; the buffer needs to grow as necessary, presumably via `realloc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to read the complete file do the following:

1. Open the file
2. Use `fstat` - see [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) - to get the size
3. `malloc` the buffer i.e. `buffer = malloc(fileStats.st_size);`
4. Read the file `fread(buffer, fileStats.st_size, 1);`
5. Close the file.
6. Play with the buffer to your hearts content.

You may wish to add one to the buffer size to place the null character into it.

Comment: For the typical HTML page acceptable. But if you'd process large data dumps like that, you're just wasting memory. The OPs request is one of those few, that can be trivially implemented on buffer blocks.

Comment: The question asks (and I quote) **problem with reading all of the text file**. Personally I would put an upper limit on the size to be read.

Comment: Reading all of the text file does not imply, that the whole text file is present in program memory at some point. This is like reading a book: Even if you read all of a book you do it page by page, yet eventually you'll have processed it all.

Comment: @datenwolf - But it is not a book! I read that the whole file needs to be read. His is highlighted in the supplied code that the buffer is of fixed size and the question mentions `malloc`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of collecting all the text in a single buffer, you could just put the above in a loop and call `read()` repeatedly to fill the buffer. Process each chunk as you read it, and print out the part you've processed so far.  When you hit end-of-file (i.e., when `read()` returns 0,) stop.

Answer (score 2):

More efficient would be to use the mmap() call to map the file directly into memory:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct stat statbuf;
stat("data.txt", &statbuf);

size_t len = stat.st_size;

int fd = open("data.txt",O_RDONLY);

char *buf = mmap(NULL, len, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE,fd, 0);
for( i=0; i< len; i++ ) {
   // do your own thing here
}
munmap(buf,len);
close(fd);
```

If the file is longer than 2GB then use the mmap2() call - you will have to fiddle with page sizes as the last argument is in pages (usually 4k)

Comment: In the flags argument you may want to include `MAP_POPULATE` into the flags. When you read from the file mapping normally, the actual data isn't in the page allocated for the file, and the CPU will signal an interrupt to the kernel to read from the hard drive. But `MAP_POPULATE` will immediately start fetching the data when the call is made.